# How to express IN (list of argument) in a query LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

How do you write a **linq query** to express this:

```
Select * from Table
where column IN (some values);
```

By some values, I mean **('Value1', 'Value2', 'value3', ...)**.

Thanks for helping

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Assuming

```
var some_values = new [] { "Value1", "Value2", "value3" };
```

Then:

```
data.Where(x => some_values.Contains(x))
```

Or:

```
from x in data
where some_values.Contains(x)
select x;
```

Comment: Hasn't touched C# in a while, wouldn't just `data.Where(some_values.Contains)` do?

Comment: @Joker_vD Think so, yes...?

Comment: True, i just like it more because it's seems more readable to me

Comment: @Joker_vD Yes, sure would. Which is more readable is a subjective thing, so you should pick the one you (and your team, if applicable) think is more readable.

Comment: That was rather easy. Thank you.

Comment: @Gert Arnold, `Enumerable.Contains` *is* a `Func<T,bool>` so no need for a `delegate`