# What is lambda equivalent an SQL "in" statement?

Tags: c#, sql, lambda

I can't figure out a lambda equivalent of this sql statement:

```
select * from Document
where Document.OrginalDocumentNumber
      in (select documentAccess.DocumentId from documentAccess where userId='1')
```

The problem is that Document & documentaccess tables have no relation to each other.
Any help would be so much appreciated.

Comment: Are you sure you mean `lambda` or do you mean `linq`? Lambdas and linq are not the same

Comment: Possible duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/16511042/how-to-express-in-list-of-argument-in-a-query-linq/16511072#16511072

Comment: Contains or variation of Any in LINQ could work.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Replace IN with EXISTS and you get following:

```
from d in dbContext.Documents 
where dbContext.documentAccesses.Any(
    x=>x.DocumentId == d.OrginalDocumentNumber && x.userId == '1' )
select d
```

Answer (score 0):

Normally, if you have sensible navigation properties, you can avoid `join` or sub-queries directly:

```
var documents = from documentAccess in contex.DocumentAccesses
                where documentAccess.UserId == 1
                select documentAccess.Document;
```

You may want to use `.Distinct()` on the results, depending on your data.

Similarly:

```
var documents = contex.DocumentAccesses
                      .Where(access => access.UserId == 1)
                      .Select(access => access.Document);
```

And even better, if you already have a `User` in context:

```
var documents = currentUser.DocumentAccesses.Select(access => access.Document);
```

Comment: thnaks for your answer but i want select from documents and documentaccess not related by document

Comment: @Well, that's a shame. `DocumentAccess` has a `DocumentId`, so it *can* contain a `Document` property. Configuring the foreign key and mapping correctly can save development time later: the Entity Framework is very good at writing joins or other structures for you.